# Trouble closing pdf window displayed in .net modal dialog Adobe Reader “protected mode” enabled

Tags: adobe, protected-mode

Hi ~ We have just updated Adobe Reader to DC.  I've spent days searching for a solution to my problem but have come up empty. The situation is this..I am rendering a byte string in a .net aspx page that is launched as a modal dialog with code like this:

```
        Contents = some byte string
        Response.Clear()

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.BinaryWrite(Contents)
        Response.End()
```

Easy right? The pdf shows up and everything works just fine. The problem is when I close the dialog box taking 20 seconds or more to close (window.close();).  I have the most recent Adobe updates and yes, unchecking 'Enable Protected Mode at startup' solves the problem but our customers are not comfortable with this solution so I've been tasked to figure out an alternate solution without rewriting our entire application.  Can anyone provide insight as to what the checkbox is actually doing that might cause a delay on a window.close? One caveat, my local machine does not have this problem even with the checkbox checked. My machine: IE11/Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.  Server with the problem: IE10/Windows Server 2012 Standard 64-bit.   Customers: setups unknown.  So I've been focusing more on the differences between my local machine and our server 2012 machine going through the registry, IE settings and Adobe settings.  Nothing stands out so here I am praying for the knowledge of someone else.  Thanks for any help you can provide.